# collision in android not detected

Tags: android, collision

I am developing an Android game in which the bird should be able to dodge the objects approaching it using the accelerometer sensor.

This code *should* detect collision, but it isn't. Can anyone tell what the problem is?

```
do{
            random(); //for generating random no.k//moving objects using animations.
            TranslateAnimation animation_plane = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 800.0f);
            animation_plane.setDuration(4500);
            animation_plane.setRepeatCount(i);
            TranslateAnimation animation_superman = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 800.0f);
            animation_superman.setDuration(3000);
            animation_superman.setRepeatCount(i);
            TranslateAnimation animation_space = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 800.0f);
            animation_space.setDuration(2500);
            animation_space.setRepeatCount(i); if (answer % 2 == 0)  //answer is random int being generated
                plane.startAnimation(animation_plane);
            if (answer % 3 == 0)
                superman.startAnimation(animation_superman);
            if (answer % 4 == 0 || answer % 5 == 0)
                spaceship.startAnimation(animation_space);
    bird_x = bird.getX();//for getting position of objects and bird.          
    bird_y = bird.getY();
    plane_x = plane.getX();
    plane_y = plane.getY();
    superman_x = superman.getX();
    superman_y = superman.getY();
    spaceship_x = spaceship.getX();
    spaceship_y = spaceship.getY();
         if(spaceship.getTranslationY()>660)
            {
                score+=1;
                newscore="score = "+score+"";
                text.setText(newscore);
            }
            if(superman.getTranslationY()>660)
            {
                score+=1;
                newscore="score = "+score+"";
                text.setText(newscore);
            }
            if(plane.getTranslationY()>660)
            {
                score+=1;
                newscore="score = "+score+"";
                text.setText(newscore);
            }
        }while(bird.getTranslationX()!=plane.getTranslationX()||bird.getTranslationX()!=spaceship.getTranslationX()||bird.getTranslationX()!=superman.getTranslationX());`
```

Answer (score 0):

Should your while condition use && instead of ||?

I'm struggling to follow the logic in this game, but I'm assuming you get a point once the plane/spaceship/superman goes to the bottom of the screen, meaning you've dodged it? If any of the objects aligns with the bird X position, the loop ends, and the game ends?

You may also need to check that the bird Y position is the same as the object Y position too.

Comment: no it should be using || and i checked it with Y positions as well.

Comment: If this is the entire code you have for the collision detection then I'm not seeing where you compare the bird Y position with any object Y position. Something like bird.getTranslationY() != plane.getTranslationY()